# Convergence/Divergence of $x_{n}=\left ( -1 \right )^{n} \left ( 1+n^{-1} \right )$ and $n=1,2,3,4...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is how i solved it:

$$x_{n}=\left ( -1 \right )^{n} \left ( 1+n^{-1} \right )$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}=\left ( -1-\frac{1}{1} \right )+\left ( 1+\frac{1}{2} \right )+\left ( -1-\frac{1}{3} \right )+\left ( 1+\frac{1}{4} \right )...$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}=-\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}=-1\left ( \frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4} \right... )$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}=-1\left ( \ln(1+1) \right... )$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}=-\ln(2)$$

$\therefore $ The Series converges to $-\ln2$

Is this correct? I am new to this topic and don't know what the correct answer to this is.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can't do it this way, since $(-1)^n$ does not converge to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left ( -1 \right )^{n} \left ( 1+n^{-1} \right )$$
does not converge since $\left ( -1 \right )^{n} \left ( 1+n^{-1} \right )$ does not converge to $0$ (it does not converge at all).

What you are doing is not correct: the step from
$$\left ( -1-\frac{1}{1} \right )+\left ( 1+\frac{1}{2} \right )+\left ( -1-\frac{1}{3} \right )+\left ( 1+\frac{1}{4} \right )+\dots$$
to
$$ -\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots$$
implies you are rearranging the terms: you are sticking together the $+1$s to the $-1$s. But you are allowed to change order in the sum of a series iff you have absolute convergence (and that's not the case).

This can be easily seen by considering the simpler series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n=1-1+1-1+1-1+1-1+\dots$$
Using your reasoning you could obtain
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n=(1-1)+(1-1)+(1-1)+\dots=0+0+0+\dots=0\ ,$$
but also
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n=1+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+(-1+1)+\dots=1+0+0+0+\dots=1\ ,$$
which are clearly inconsistent.